# After I setup nginx load balancing my wordpress Post Pagination url not Working

Tags: wordpress, post, nginx, pagination, load-balancing

I have setup with digital ocean 1 nginx load balancer(round-robin) -> 2 webserver -> 1 database server.

All Url working fine. Problem only on post pagination url.

Example url : https://www.jokescoff.com/top-5-solid-bheja-fry-funny-hindi-jokes.html  (This page working)

https://www.jokescoff.com/top-5-solid-bheja-fry-funny-hindi-jokes.html/2 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc pages not working)

What should I do?